# App Engine pipeline - should I be using return_task=True for more reliable?

Tags: google-app-engine, appengine-pipeline

Today while browsing the source I noticed this comment in `Pipeline.start` method:

```
Returns:
  A taskqueue.Task instance if return_task was True. This task will *not*
  have a name, thus to ensure reliable execution of your pipeline you
  should add() this task as part of a separate Datastore transaction.
```

Interesting, I *do* want *reliable* execution of my pipeline after all.

I suspect the comment is a bit inaccurate, since if you use the default `return_task=False` option the task is added inside a transaction anyway (by `_PipelineContext.start`)... it seems like the reason you'd want to add the task yourself is only if you want the starting of the pipeline to depend on success of something in your own transaction.

Can anyone confirm my suspicion or suggest how else following the comment's advice may effect 'reliable execution of your pipeline' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **don't** include the parameter when you call `Pipeline.start()`, the task is enqueued in the queue given by the Pipeline's inner variable context (type `_PipelineContext`). The default name for this queue is `"default"`.

If you **do** include the parameter when you call `Pipeline.start()`, the task is not enqueued within these methods. `Pipeline.start()` will return `_PipelineContext.start()`, we see that it relies on an inner method `txn()`. This method is annotated transactional since it first does a bit of book-keeping for the Datastore records used to run this pipeline. Then, after this book-keeping is done, it creates a task without a `name` property (see [the Task class definition here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks#Task_name)).

If **`return_task`** was not provided, it will go ahead and add that (un-named) task to the default queue for this pipeline's context. It also sets `transactional` on that task, so that it will be a "transactional task" which will only be added if the enclosing datastore transaction is committed successfully (ie. with all the bookkeeping in the `txn()` method successful so that this task, when run, will interact properly with the other parts of the pipeline etc.)

If, on the other hand, **`return_task`** was *not* defined, the un-named task, un-added to a queue, is returned. The `txn()` book-keeping work will nonetheless have taken place to prepare it to run. `_PipelineContext.start()` returns to `Pipeline.start()`, and user code will get the un-named, un-added task.

You're absolutely correct to say that the reason you would want this pattern is if you want pipeline execution to be part of a transaction in your code. Maybe you want to receive and store some data, kick off a pipeline, and store the pipeline id on a user's profile somewhere in Datastore. Of course, this means you want not only the datastore events but also the pipeline execution event to be grouped together into this atomic transaction. This pattern would allow you to do such a thing. If the transaction failed, the transactional task would not execute, and `handle_run_exception()` will be able to catch the [`TransactionFailedError`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/exceptions#TransactionFailedError) and run pipeline.abort() to make sure the Datastore book-keeping data had been destroyed for the task that never ran.

The fact that the pipeline is un-named will not cause any disruption, since un-named tasks are auto-generated a unique name when added to a queue if the name is undefined, and in fact [*not* having a name is actually a requirement for tasks which are added with `transactional=True`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks#Task_add).

All in all, I think the comment just means to say that due to the fact that the task returned is transactional, in order for it to be reliably executed, you should make sure that the `task.add (queue_name...)` takes place in a transaction. It's not saying that the returned task is somehow "unreliable" just because you set `return_task`, it's basically using the word "reliable" superfluously, due to the fact that the task is run in a transaction.